# Sin2x mclaurin series python matplotlib numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import factorial as fact

def maths(x, b):
    maths = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(b):
        maths = maths + (-1)**i * (2*x)**(2*i + 1)/fact(2*i +1)
    return maths
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
img = plt.figure()
img = plt.clf()
ax = img.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot = (x, np.sin(2*x))
ax.plot = (x, maths(x, 8))
ax.set_ylim([-10,10])
ax.legend()
```

does anyone understand how to fix this, i would like to create a mclaurin series with value of sin(2x)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the math part in your code, however the coding part is a little bit off.

Here are a few points:

You should `import numpy as np` and not <s>`import numpy as py`</s>. Later you use it as `np` anyway.

The function named `maths` has a variable called `maths`. Despite it works, it's as confusing as it can be. Rename the function, or the variable.

If you create a new figure, there is no need to clear it immediately.

```py
img = plt.figure()
img = plt.clf() <-- remove this
```

`ax.plot = (x, np.sin(2*x))` is wrong. You wanted to call `ax.plot`, and not assign to it.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import factorial as fact

def mclaurin(x, order):
    maths = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(order):
        maths += (-1)**i * (2*x)**(2*i + 1)/fact(2*i +1)
    return maths

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, np.sin(2 * x))
ax.plot(x, mclaurin(x, 8))
ax.set(ylim=(-2, 2))
```

Comment: thank you so much, didn't notice i did import numpy as py no wonder it didn't work